# Unity - Text not properly align

Tags: unity

My text doesn't seem properly align to top left even I already set it in `Rect Transform`.

[image]

[image]

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seem to me that you only changed the pivot point of the text, not the position. You can see the location of the text is relative to the pivot point which is X: 430, y: -223.

You need to hold shift & alt when align the text to top left to also change the position and pivot point of the text.

Alternatively, you can set your x, y, z coordinate of the text to 0, 0, 0 to move it to the pivot point.

Answer (score 1):

When changing the alignment press ALT before clicking the top left corner, else you'll just set the pivot point.